# Create new document?

Tags: document

When right click is pressed and create new document is highlighted there is only one option [empty document]. How more options can be placed [like new libre office writer document] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved with the link below.

http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2006/12/08/how-to-create-easy-access-templates-via-right-click-ubuntu-510-6061-610/

> "For example, save a blank OpenOffice.org document (call it
>   OpenOffice.odt) into templates folder and you’ll now have a
>   quick-launch for a blank OpenOffice document. Save a blank .txt file
>   inside the templates folder for quick access to an empty Text Editor
>   file. Even save a template .html file to the folder and have quick
>   access to any html templates you work on. This works great if you ever
>   work from file templates and need to re-create them on the fly."

Comment: Is there a way for multi-file templates? Like, "New HTML project" should give a folder with `index.html`, `js/javascript.js` and `styles/style.css`